# How to specify cabal options for an external dependency in package.yaml?

Tags: haskell, yaml, haskell-stack

I would like to use an external package from `Hackage`, which exposes additional features after being compiled with some flags. Using cabal, I must compile this way: `"cabal install -fserver -fc-runtime"`. How can I specify this flags in the `package.yaml`? I tried to use `extra-deps` and `ghc-options`, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure if to use them is appropriate at all.

For now, I have this error:

> "Error while parsing $.ghc-options - expected String, encountered
>   Object."

Answer (score -1):

You probably want:

```
flags:
  package-name:
    server: true
    c-runtime: true
```

Here is the related section of documentation: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#flags